# How to use regex with can be empty?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing some easy web application to practice my skill.

I'm using a regex to validate my phone input like this,

```
var reg = /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;

if(!reg.test($('#input-phone').val())){
    alert('error');
}
```

It works normally but it can't be empty. I don't know how to modify this to be able to reject empty field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether there is a value if so then use the regex

```
var reg = /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;
var phone = $('#input-phone').val();
if (phone.length && !reg.test(phone)) {
    alert('error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression matches an empty string because all of its individual sequences are *optional*.

The easiest way of ensuring there is some data inside the expression is to add a lookahead for a single character at the start:

```
var reg = /^(?=.)[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;
```

However, it may be easier still to explicitly test if the variable is empty before doing the regex test.